# How to search titles that contain string in sql and push results into an array

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

Okay, I'm quite new to Mysql and I can't find a simple solution to my question. I want to search my database and return all instances of a string. ex: user types "hello world" and database returns queries of "hello my name is world" etc. I'll take these results and push them into a php array.

here's my attempt of it according to [this](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/17/simple-text-searching-using-like):

```
include '../config.php';
$con = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME .'', DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

$firstsearcharray = array(); // push into this array
$searchqueryarray = explode(" ",$searchquery);//$searchquery is data sent from AJAX
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM srating where MATCH(title) AGAINST (':searchqueryarray')");
$query->bindParam(':$searchqueryarray',$searchqueryarray);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//I have to somehow push each result into an array (possibly using array_push and a for loop)
```

I believe that the way I'm searching isn't optimal. I would prefer to use CONTAINS over LIKE as I've heard that it is faster, but it is way less documented than LIKE.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for fulltext search.

An example:

```
SELECT id,prod_name, match( prod_name )
AGAINST ( '+harpoon +article' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance
FROM testproduct 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

`Like` and `contains` are a waste of time.

Comment: so to clarify: 
-id is the actual column called id
-prod_name is the name of the table
-testproduct is the array that I'm sending in to be searched (in this case it is $searchqueryarray)

now how do I retrieve the data through a php variable (ex: $firstsearcharray)
i've looked through the article and +harpoon and +article doesn't make sense
-I put it in a PDO ex: $query = $con->prepare("SELECT id,prod_name, match( prod_name )AGAINST ( '+harpoon +article' INNATURALLANGUAGE MODE)ASrelevanceFROMtestproductORDER BY relevance DESC");
thanks for your answer and I'll continue to search for a solution

Comment: It was just an example and different table structure, but to point you to concept with the url provided. Let me give you a link in a second to a somewhat complete example using it. Hold on

Comment: Keep in mind that fulltext search in any dbms is probably going to disappoint. For robust search many of us integrate with systems like `solr` that have one focus (search)

Comment: yea after I find the queries, I'll do additional steps on my searched queries to further my search ex: look inside the files and count the number of occurrences of a string